# How do I use "NOT IN" in a query?

Tags: 7, database

What is the proper way to write a query containing 'NOT IN' using a condition statement?

My query is the following one:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT nid FROM node WHERE language NOT IN 
  (SELECT language 
    FROM languages WHERE language = 'ab');
```

I've tried something like the following:

```
$query->condition('n.' . $key, $value, 'not in (select language from 
  languages where language = $value)');
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing the obvious, but what is the difference between your query and `SELECT nid FROM node WHERE language != 'ab'`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the specific example, you should simply write the condition as:

```
$query->condition('n.language', 'ab', '<>');
```

In the generic case, where you need to select the rows in a database basing on the values returned from a sub-query, you should consider what follows:

- "NOT IN" is accepted as operator from `SelectQuery::condition()`. In fact, the following query would be executed:

  ```
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n');
  $query->condition('n.nid', array(1, 2, 3), 'NOT IN');
  $nodes = $query->execute();

  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    dsm($node->nid);
  }
  ```
- As reported in [Conditional clauses](http://drupal.org/node/310086) ("Subselects"), `SelectQuery::condition()` accepts  also an object implementing `SelectQueryInterface` as value for `$value`, such as the one returned by `db_select()`; the problem is that actually you can just use it when the value of `$operator` is equal to `"IN"`. See [Subselects don't work in DBTNG conditions, except when used as value for IN](http://drupal.org/node/1267508).

The only way I can see to use the "NOT IN" operator with a sub-query in `condition` is to:

- Execute the subquery to get an array
- Execute the main query setting the condition as in the following snippet

  ```
  $query->condition($key, $subquery_result, 'NOT IN');
  ```

  `$subquery_result` is the array containing the result of the sub-query.

Otherwise, you could use `where()` as others said, which accepts a string for the part of the query you need to add.

Keep in mind that `db_select()` is slower that `db_query()`; you should use the first when you know the query could be altered by other modules. Otherwise, if other modules are not supposed to use `hook_query_alter()` to alter your query, you should use `db_query()`.
In the case of accessing nodes, if you need to obtain only the nodes to which a user has access, then you need to use `db_select()` and add `'node_access'` as tag of the query, with [`SelectQuery::addTag()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddTag/7.x). For example, [`blog_page_last()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21blog%21blog.pages.inc/function/blog_page_last/7.x) uses the following code.

```
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')->extend('PagerDefault');
  $nids = $query
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'sticky', 'created'))
    ->condition('type', 'blog')
    ->condition('status', 1)
    ->orderBy('sticky', 'DESC')
    ->orderBy('created', 'DESC')
    ->limit(variable_get('default_nodes_main', 10))
    ->addTag('node_access')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchCol();
```

Similar code is used by [`book_block_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21book%21book.module/function/book_block_view/7.x).

```
$select = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('title'))
  ->condition('n.nid', $node->book['bid'])
  ->addTag('node_access');
$title = $select->execute()->fetchField();
```

Comment: Here is an example of a subquery for a views custom filter I've written: [link](https://github.com/rogercodina/views_adjuntos_filter/blob/master/inc/views_adjuntos_filter.views.inc)

Comment: "Subselects don't work in DBTNG conditions, except when used as value for IN" is fixed in Drupal 8.3

Answer (score 5):

When writing complex queries you should definitely use [`db_query()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_query/7) instead of [`db_select()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_select/7).

1. You can't write a `NOT IN` clause with a subquery with the current Drupal database API (it's a [know issue](http://drupal.org/node/1267508) being worked out).
2. If you don't need your query to be [dynamic](http://drupal.org/node/310075) (hence rewritten by others modules), [don't bother](http://drupal.org/node/835068#comment-3125136) trying to write such a complex one with `db_select()`.
3. Subqueries aren't well supported yet (see a [previous answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/8556/594) of mine) and if you're used to write SQL it's way easier to use `db_query()`.

Regarding your query, I'm not sure why you want to use a subquery (unless you simplified your exemple) ? You can write it easily like this:

```sql
SELECT nid 
FROM node n INNER JOIN languages l ON n.language = l.language
WHERE language NOT IN ('ab')
```

`DISTINCT` isn't necessary as `nid` is a primary key so it won't be duplicated.

Comment: Regarding #2, the OP is selecting nodes. AFAIK db_select() is the only way to provide any required 'node_access' tag, in which case db_select() would be the only choice.

Answer (score 4):

There's also [where()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--query.inc/function/QueryConditionInterface%3a%3awhere/7) which allows to add an arbitrary where condition to the query.

Example:

```
$query->where('n.language NOT IN (SELECT language FROMlanguages WHERE language = :lang)', array(':lang' => $value));
```

As keithm mentioned, you must use db_select() and addTag('node_access') when selecting nodes which are then displayed to users.

Comment: This worked for me, except I had to move it so it wasn't directly before a `$query->range()` command (and possibly before any `$query->join()` commands) or else an SQL syntax error was thrown.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to use db_select with a NOT IN subselect is just to use the little known

[$query->where](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3a%3awhere/7)

to add an arbitrary where condition.

e.g:

```
  // Count query for users without rid 3
  $query = db_select('users', 'u');
  $query->fields('u', array('uid'));
  $query->where('u.uid NOT IN(select uid from {users_roles} where rid = :rid)', array(':rid' => 3));  
  $count = $query->countQuery()->execute()->fetchField();
  drupal_set_message($count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Where $subquery_values is an array of $key => $nid format  as result of a subquery

```
$query->condition('node.nid', array_values($subquery_values), "NOT IN");
```

it works fine.