# Retrieve the list of users who have not taken the quiz

Tags: users, quiz

```
  $all_users =db_select('users', 'u')
  ->fields('u', array('uid'))
  ->execute()
  ->fetchAll();

  $quiz_nid = db_select('quiz_node_properties ', 'qnp')->distinct()
    ->fields('qnp',array('nid'))
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();

    foreach ($quiz_nid as $key => $value) {
      $quiz_id = $quiz_nid[$key]->nid;
      $quiz_takers = db_select('quiz_node_results', 'qnr')->distinct()
        ->fields('qnr',array('uid'))
        ->condition('nid',$quiz_id,'=')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchAll();
    }
```

$all_users is the list of all users.
$quiz_takers is the list of users who have taken the quiz.
Both $all_users and $quiz_takers are array of objects.
I want list of users who have not taken the quiz. **($all_users - $quiz_takers)**.
How to achieve this using **not in**(database query) or anything.
Help needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite straightforward by using a custom function. I think udiff might work too, but I'm going without that.

But before that make one modification

```
$quiz_takers_uid = db_select('quiz_node_results', 'qnr')->distinct()
        ->fields('qnr',array('uid'))id
        ->condition('nid',$quiz_id,'=')
        ->execute()
        ->fetchCol();
```

This gives you an array of uids in quiz_takers_uid.

```
function getdiff($all_users,$quiz_takers_uid) {
  $remaining_users = array();
  foreach ($allusers as $user) {
    if (array_search($user->uid,$quiz_takers_uid) !== FALSE)
      continue;
    else 
      $remaining_users[] = $user->uid;
  }
  return $remaining_users;
}
```

I just thought of something else, which would make it even shorter
In fact, an alternative solution would be to also make

```
$all_users_uid =db_select('users', 'u')
  ->fields('u', array('uid'))
  ->execute()
  ->fetchCol();
```

then you could just do `$remaining_users = array_diff($all_users_uid, $quiz_takers_uid);`

as both are now arrays of uid.

Answer (score 0):

If you have two array (one containing all the student, and another containing nids of students who took the quiz) than you try [array_diff()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php): Computes the difference of arrays

> $result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

Example:

```
<?php
  $array1 = array("a" => "green", "red", "blue", "red");
  $array2 = array("b" => "green", "yellow", "red");
  $result = array_diff($array1, $array2);

  print_r($result);
?>
```

The result will be `Array ([1] => blue)`, you can see here the difference will of array1 from array2 so the result contains the elements of array1 not present in array2.

And this would be helpful as it won't require the additional database call.

---

However if you want to do it with the `db_select` query than check [How do I use “NOT IN” in a query](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18497/how-do-i-use-not-in-in-a-query):

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')->fields('n');
$query->condition('n.nid', array(1, 2, 3), 'NOT IN');
$nodes = $query->execute();
```

> $query->condition('n.nid', $array2, 'NOT IN');

Comment: I have array of objects in both the cases. how to find out the difference between array of objects.?

Comment: @neetumorwani Instead of `fetchAll` in your query USE `->fetchAllAssoc('uid');
  $user_ids = array_keys($all_users);`, this will provide you the `uid`s or `nid` in an array