# I install ultimate cron and I saw that errors

Tags: 7, cron

I have all this error but when i am running cron without cron ultimate all run perfect but with cron ultimate i got that errors... Could anyone help i really need help here:

```
    exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
    or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
    the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
    syntax to use near '))' at line 1' in
    /var/www/html/drupal7.36/includes/database/database.inc:2171
    Stack trace:
    #0 /var/www/html/drupal7.36/includes/database/database.inc(2171): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
    #1 /var/www/html/drupal7.36/includes/database/database.inc(683): DatabaseStatementBase->execute(Array, Array)
    #2 /var/www/html/drupal7.36/includes/database/query.inc(858): DatabaseConnection->query('DELETE FROM {er...', Array, Array)
    #3 /var/www/html/drupal7.36/sites/all/modules/bla/includes/bla.functions.inc(245): DeleteQuery->execute()
    #4 /var/www/html/drupal7.36/sites/all/modules/bla/bla.module(56): bla_clean()
    #5 [internal function]:bla_cron()
    #6 /var/www/html/drupal7.36/sites/all/modules/ultimate_cron/ultimate_cron.module(941): call_user_func('bla_...')
    #7 [internal function]: _ultimate_cron_run_hook('bla_...', Array)
    #8 /var/www/html/drupal7.36/sites/all/modules/background_process/background_process.module(574): call_user_func_array('_ultimate_cron_...', Array)
    #9 /var/www/html/drupal7.36/sites/all/modules/background_process/background_proces
    s.module(503): background_process_service_execute('uc:error_log_ji...', false)
    #10 [internal function]: background_process_service_start('uc%3Aerror_log_...')
    #11 /var/www/html/drupal7.36/includes/menu.inc(519): call_user_func_array('background_proc...', Array)
    #12 /var/www/html/drupal7.36/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
    #13 {main}

function blabla_clean() {
  $number = variable_get('blabla_number_select');
  // Keeps values equal to the number that user had selected.
  $query = db_select('blabla', 'j')
    ->fields('j')
    ->range(0, $number)
    ->orderBy('j.timestamp', 'DESC');
  $ids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();

  // Deletes all the other values.
  db_delete('blabla')
    ->condition('wid', $ids, 'NOT IN')
    ->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue isn't Ultimate cron, per se. It's your custom `bla` module; it's running some function called `bla_clean()` that's building a Delete SQL query with broken syntax. When executed, it's producing the error.

You're using the NOT IN operator incorrectly. Here's a [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/18514/45675) that demonstrates a NOT IN within a query.